# Getting sudden Grunt task not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-cli

I'm stumped with this one.  I been using Grunt for a while now via CLI and WebStorm.  Today I was running some manual Grunt tasks via the WebStorm Grunt panel and something magically seem to have happened that I could not longer run any tasks on this project (neither via WebStorm nor the command line).  I've tried everything from reinstalling grunt/grunt-cli, rebooting my PC, abbreviating the grunt file to no avail.  Below is a super abbreviated Gruntfile.js with the problem output.  Any ideas as to what may have happened and how to restore my build environment are greatly appreciated!

```
Carlos@XPS8500 ~/git/Test
$ cat Gruntfile.js
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '.',
                        src: 'package.json',
                        dest: 'package.xxx'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', 'Test', function(){

        grunt.task.run('copy:dist');

    });
};

Carlos@XPS8500 ~/git/Test
$ grunt --verbose test
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Initializing config...OK
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ test

Running tasks: test

Running "test" task
Warning: Task "copy:dist" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Carlos@XPS8500 ~/git/Test
```

Comment: Darn it, the package.json got overridden thus all the grunt packages were missing.  I guess in hindsight the error message did make sense.

Comment: Incidentally, I've seen this too when the json in package.json is invalid (like an extra comma, for instance).